# How to allocate weights in OWA operator in fuzzy logic

Tags: fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

I am reading about OWA operators in fuzzy logic from the article [here](http://uni-obuda.hu/users/fuller.robert/rem961.pdf)

In the example provided in page **21** it says that the weights associated with the linguistic quantifier are  for $a=1.2$ are

`0.116,0.151,0.168,0.180,0.189,0.196`

As I understand the linguistic Operator that is referred here is
$Q_a(r)=r^{(a)},a>=0$
Can someone please explain how the weights are obtained?
What is this `r` in  $Q_A(r)=r^{(a)},a>=0$ ?

Also  how is the value of `a` determined?

Can someone please explain these.